# Mapsforge on tap listeners for more than one marker

Tags: android, mapsforge

I am following the **mapsforge** library for some time now and I love the workings of the library.

In my project, I need different types of markers. One type should display a dialog, regarding the marker, when tapped and another type should make a toast of the marker's coordinates when tapped.

So I create two child classes of the Marker class say PoiMarker and LocationMarker and thus override the methods of **onTap()** for both the child classes. Now when I add the first marker(**PoiMarker**) it's all good and the dialog is shown. Then when I add the second marker(**LocationMarker**) the toast is also displayed, but when i tap on the first marker it displays a toast instead of a dialog. And any where i tap on the map it displays me a toast instead of a dialog.

I realize that when adding a marker to the mapview we are adding a layer to the mapview and when I add another marker the new layer just overlays the previous marker and the tap to the first marker is never encountered.

How do I make the first marker tappable even after I add a new second marker?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create multiple class for multiple marker Type, just create a new class, extend marker and add markerType property and override onTap:

```
public class DescriptedMarker extends Marker {

public DescriptedMarker(LatLong latLong, Bitmap bitmap, int horizontalOffset, int verticalOffset) {
    super(latLong, bitmap, horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);
}

public String marker_description;
public int  marker_type;

private Runnable action;

public void setOnTabAction(Runnable action){

    this.action = action;
}
@Override
public boolean onTap(LatLong tapLatLong, Point layerXY, Point tapXY) {

    double centerX = layerXY.x + getHorizontalOffset();
    double centerY = layerXY.y + getVerticalOffset();

    double radiusX = (getBitmap().getWidth() / 2) *1.1;
    double radiusY = (getBitmap().getHeight() / 2) *1.1;


    double distX = Math.abs(centerX - tapXY.x);
    double distY = Math.abs(centerY - tapXY.y);


    if( distX < radiusX && distY < radiusY){

        if(action != null){
            action.run();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

now you can easily create multiple type of market:

```
org.mapsforge.core.graphics.Bitmap bmp = AndroidGraphicFactory.convertToBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myMarkerDrawable));
//pos is a LatLong variable 
final DescriptedMarker marker = new DescriptedMarker(pos,bmp,0,0);  
marker.marker_type = x; //x is an int and determine marker type


   marker.setOnTabAction(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

           if(marker.marker_type == 0)
           Application.toast_short(marker.marker_description);
           else if(marker.marker_type == 1)
           {
               //display a dialog for example
           }// you can add many if for many types
       }
   });
```